# Android | Correct way to get and compress bitmap | Out of memory

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

In my app, I get an image (bitmap) with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select"), GET_CODE);
```

Then, in `onActivityResult` I get the bitmap from uri, with:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), uri); //here I've the error
```

And with big image, I get the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 268435468 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 167MB until OOM
```

How can compress bitmap correctly?

Comment: Well, the bitmap is already compressed, if you just read it in using a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`. You would also use `getType()` to determine the actual MIME type, since you are accepting a wildcard. Decompressing it and re-compressing it will be a waste of time.

Comment: Do you get this error while creating Bitmap object or while you trying to load it somewhere? It's not problem of compression, but problem of appropriate size of memory to be allocated.

Comment: @CommonsWare do you can an example?

Comment: @piotr.wittchen I get the error with `Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), uri);`, when I try to get bitmap from uri.

Comment: your Image large. It will OutOfMemory. You must rezise image !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As CommonsWare said, the bitmap is already compressed.
Do you want the original image ? if not necessarily, you can resize the bitmap pretty easily, like that :

```
private static Bitmap decodeBitmap(Context context, Uri theUri, int sampleSize) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = sampleSize;

    AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = null;
    try {
        fileDescriptor = context.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(theUri, "r");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Bitmap actuallyUsableBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(
            fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), null, options);

    Log.d(TAG, options.inSampleSize + " sample method bitmap ... "
            + actuallyUsableBitmap.getWidth() + " " + actuallyUsableBitmap.getHeight());

    return actuallyUsableBitmap;
}
```

More infos about inSampleSize here :
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize

Also if you don't need transparency on the bitmap, you can add the param inPreferredConfig to RGB_565 in the options :
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inPreferredConfig

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I need!